# Find the minimum number of edges of the graph, given 34 vertices and and each edge has at least 7 edges

Tags: graph-theory

The question is this: An undirected graph G has 34 vertices and the degree of each vertex is at least 7. What is the minimum number of edges that the graph G can have?

The answer has been given as 119.

I thought of doing Breadth-First-Search but I think it may not be the correct way to go. How should I proceed?

Comment: $\dfrac{34\cdot7}2=119$, it is as simple as that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes but can it be achieved?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin, Thank you for answering. Have we used the handshaking lemma here?

Comment: No, the handshaking lemma does not tell you that the graph exists. (It only tells you that it doesn't when it doesn't, which is not the case.) To prove that it exists, you either use the Havel–Hakimi algorithm, or just build such graph (which is rather trivial).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, such graph can be constructed in a pretty simple way.

First, let's number vertices $0, 1, 2, ..., 33$. Between vertices $x$ and $y$, we draw an edge if and only if $|x−y| \in \{1, 2, 3, 17, 31, 32, 33\}$. It is not difficult to prove that the degree of all vertices are $7$.

In general, for all non-negative integers $n$ and $d$ such that $d \lt n$, the graph with $n$ vertices and all degrees are $d$ exists when $nd$ is even (however, if $nd$ is odd, it contradicts to handshaking lemma). For all such $(n, d)$, it can be constructed in a similar way that conditions by $|x-y|$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a source for this second fact?

Comment: @BenjaminWang It is a well-known fact which is (also) written in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph). The proof is a thing which I have came up with, but I think it's most probably non-original.